# http async response handling with pistache framework

Tags: c++, multithreading, http, asynchronous, barrier

I am trying to write a c++ pistache server that, on a specific endpoint, has to contact another pistache server.
This is the scenario:

client -> server1 -> server2

client <- server1 <- server2

I am having problems waiting for the response in server1 and sending it back to the client asynchronously.

More in details:
I think that an efficient way of handling this problem should be to call the response.send in the resp.then block (it returns a Pistache::Async::Promise). Unluckily, it gives a segmentation fault once that endpoint is called and it gets in the then block. So I guess it is illegal to do that as I wanted. Also, the logs are not giving more details than segmentation fault, so it is hard to debug.

I share my server1 code to show you how I did implement it.

```
void doSmth(const Rest::Request& request, Http::ResponseWriter httpResponse)
    {
      
        
        auto resp_srv2 = client
                    .post(addr)
                    .body(json)
                    .send();    
        resp_srv2.then(
        [&](Http::Response response) {
            httpResponse.send(r.response_code);             
        },
        [&](std::exception_ptr exc) {
            PrintException excPrinter;
            excPrinter(exc);
    });


    }
```

In this case, I could avoid using the barrier as shown in the [pistache git repo](https://github.com/pistacheio/pistache/blob/master/examples/http_client.cc). Using their code, 28k requests from the user are correctly handled, and then I guess that the resources are not correctly allocated since it gets stuck.

Do you know how to send the response to the client once received the server2 response asynchronously? I need to do it in an optimized way and correctly allocate all the resources.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Does `send` return a promise? If yes, when do you actually call the promise (or wait for the result to come back)? From what I understand, `then` just specifies what is to be done in case of success or error. But you don't seem to be waiting for promise to get fulfilled. I may be wrong in my assumptions though.

Comment: You need to `wait_for` promise to get fulfilled. See the example: https://github.com/pistacheio/pistache/blob/615281a33eccd9c1d09f274254fd28313b0cd582/examples/http_client.cc#L69

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I know and I already tried it doing so:

        Async::Barrier<Http::Response> barrier(resp);
        barrier.wait_for(std::chrono::seconds(5));

        response.send(response_code);

But the performances are bad and I get a segmentation fault after a while. I also tried to increase the number of threads for the servers but it does not change the result. 

Also the implementation you quoted is more efficient then this but I don't need to wait for multiple requests since I am using a single request and sending back the response.

Comment: Btw, if I use their implementation, as I said in the post, when I reach 28k requests it gets suck even if I do one request per second with one single user (almost 3 hours of simulation)

Comment: since I put a barrier every time the endpoint is called maybe I am allocating too many resources?
Do you know if it would be necessary to deallocate that barrier at the end of the function? If yes how to do it?

Comment: Not sure really. Maybe you can read the source code for Barrier, I see a condition_variable used in the code: https://github.com/pistacheio/pistache/blob/615281a33eccd9c1d09f274254fd28313b0cd582/include/pistache/async.h#L1155

Comment: I guess that it is the specific combination of barrier and then send message that cause some issues. The pistache team might not have handled it correctly.

Do you know some more performative solution?

Comment: No, I haven't worked with this framework so not sure. Also, I don't understand the problem you face correctly. If it's segmentation fault, you should see the back trace and see where the crash happens. If it's inside the framework, raise an issue on their Github repository.

Comment: did it, thanks
If you want to follow up
https://github.com/pistacheio/pistache/issues/1083#issue-1309958799